# Android Fragment not replacing UI from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mobile

I am currently building an android application that uses a navigation drawer. When the user selects an item from the drawer, a fragment is created that corresponds to the item selected. For example, if the user selects the contacts item from the navigation drawer, the UI should change from the dashboard, to the contacts layout.

I am successfully creating fragments, however the Fragment retains the calenderView from my dashboard.

Here is the dashboard layout:

[Here is the Dashboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puHOy.png)

Here is the layout once the user selects timer from the navigation drawer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8GsN.png)

The problem is that the calenderView remains when the fragment is inflated. Ideally it would just be the "Timer Frag" Button that is visible in this fragment.

Here is my mainActivity code:

```
//Fragments will be inflated through this method.
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_patient) {
        fragment = new Patient_Fragment();
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_timer) {
        fragment = new Timer_Fragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_reminders) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contacts) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_account) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    }

    if(fragment !=null)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.dashboardArea, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Here is my timer Fragment:

```
public class Timer_Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Here is the fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timerFrag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Timer Frag"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.181" />
```

This is the dashboard XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/dashboardArea"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.a517086.carefree.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

   <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml code where we can see the container with the id `R.id.dashboardArea`?

Comment: @beeb editied to show xml needed.

Comment: The problem is, that there is a `CalendarView` inside your xml fragment. You can't replace this view if it's statically placed inside your xml. Put the `CalendarView` inside a fragment and load it as default using `FragmentTransaction.replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your CalendarView in another xml fragment related to the calendar fragment like you did with the timer fragment like this :

fragment_calendar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

CalendarFragment.java

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Your dashboard xml file should be empty like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/dashboardArea"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.a517086.carefree.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, in your main activity initialize the calendar fragment just like that :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.add(R.id.dashboardArea, CalendarFragment);
        ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are replacing the `R.id.dashboardArea` (which is in your `CalendarView` fragment layout), but you need to replace the `View` in your `MainActivity` which will hold the fragment. I have called it `content_container` for this example.

```
if(fragment !=null)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.content_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Example:
I use a `DrawerLayout`, but you can use just any layout. This is my `MainActivity` Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When I want to swap out my fragments I just get the fragment object I want to be visible and replace the container--In this case "content_container".

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but i am already doing this. R.id.dashboardArea  is the view for my main activity. It is the name of the layout that holds the calendarView.

Comment: I see `android:id="@+id/dashboardArea"`in your `FrameLayout` in which you have your `CalendarView`. You will have a `MainActivity` that hosts the fragments. In that Activity you will have a container `View`. This container is what needs to be replaced, with the fragment you want visible.

Comment: @S.Robinson take a look at my edited post. Let me know if you have any questions.